# What are "allowed_methods" in magento's shipping method?

Tags: php, magento

I am creating a shipping module. I want to know what is the meaning of **allowed_methods** shipping method.

Can I use my own "allowed_methods" in shipping methods?

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/) about adding a custom shipping method to Magento if I correclty understand your question - you are asking about the getAllowedMethods() method?:

Next, our interface requires us to implement getAllowedMethods() which returns array of key-value pairs of all available methods, so let’s do that:

```
public function getAllowedMethods()
{
    return array(
        'standard'    =>  'Standard delivery',
        'express'     =>  'Express delivery',
    );
}
```

Comment: yes, my question is about getAllowedMethods(), what is it. what is the 'standard' and 'express'. Is it is build in methods or I can create my own too.